# Hreflang meta tags not seen on my NextJS page

Tags: next.js, seo, hreflang

I have a problem because my generated HREFLANG tags are not seen by the SEO checker tools such as https://technicalseo.com/tools/hreflang/. I am generating these in my language switcher component inside the `next/head` component.

I assume the problem is because I use `useEffect()` to built up hreflang urls?

```
export default function LanguageSwitcher() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // I am building array of hreflang URL's here from which I then generate the HTML
  }

  return (
     <Head>
       {
           languageMapper.map((l) => (
               <link key={l.locale} rel="alternate" hrefLang={l.locale} href={l.url} />
           ))
       }
     </Head>
  )
}
```

Will this be ok for Google, or should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check how your hrefLang attribute renders on the page. If it hrefLang with upper L, search engines won't see it. Rename it to hreflang, and yes it will drop you a warning about invalid DOM property, but i haven't found solution for that. I'll edit this message whenever i find right answer.